# Build a specific leftist tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, insertion

I was practicing leftist trees and saw an example of min height-biased leftist tree on the textbook:

```
        2
      /   \
     7    50
    /    /
   11   80
  /
13
```

The question is, can I use only insertions to build this example?
I tried the following insertion sequence:

```
2  7  11  13  50  80
```

and it turns out to be this one:

```
      2
    /   \
  11     7
 /  \   /
13  50 80
```

So how can I achieve this? If it is impossible, why?
Furthermore, can the example tree on the textbook be built when other operations are allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The following sequence is fine:

```
13  11  7  2  50  80
```

The idea is that the tree goes unbalanced when the sequence is descending. For example,

```
4  3  2  1
```

builds an unbalanced tree

```
      1
     /
    2
   /
  3
 /
4
```